# How to SELECT TOP (@x) or simply "all" rows in SQL Server (without SET ROWCOUNT)

Tags: sql-server

I have a flag that determines whether a result-set should be limited to a small size. The query itself is huge, and I don't want to copy/paste it because maintenance will be awful. What's the best way? I have a few alternatives I'm playing with, but they seem hack-ish to me:

**Possibility #1**

```
SELECT TOP (
    CASE WHEN @flag = 1 THEN @limit ELSE @someHugeNumber END
) (...)
FROM (...) hugeQuery;
```

**Possibility #2**

```
DECLARE @rc INT = CASE WHEN @flag = 1 THEN @limit ELSE 0 END;
SET ROWCOUNT @rc;
SELECT (...) FROM (...) hugeQuery;
```

Is there a better way? What about performance? Help appreciated!

Comment: What's wrong with the case expression for TOP? I am not a fan of using ROWCOUNT here because it means using two statements when you only need one.

Comment: What's wrong mostly is me not wanting to define a max. It's not very readable when that case is actually meant to mean "give me everything" and effectively I'm asking for no more than say, a billion. It smells to me.

Comment: When you use `set rowcount` it applies to ALL statements that run within your query (stored procedure calls, views, triggers etc). Do you really want that? Northing wrong with `top (n)` like you were told, and readability is subjective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH    q AS
        (
        /* my huge query */ 
        )
(
SELECT  TOP (@limit)
        *
FROM    q
WHERE   @flag = 1
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT  *
FROM    q
WHERE   @flag = 0
)
ORDER BY
        somefield
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

The `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` would make the optimizer to sniff the value of `@flag` and optimize either query out. The query would need to be recompiled on each invocation, though.

If you leave it off, though, the two queries would be most probably concatenated using the merge union algorithm, which would actually have almost the same performance (as one of the queries would always be empty), as long as the huge query output is sorted on `somefield`.

Comment: Or you could optimize for unknown. But how is this better than top N?

Comment: @ajeh: optimize for unknown makes a cached plan with the optimizer making no assumptions about the parameters's values. It would still have to execute both queries.